# Django form category not showing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

[image]

I am writing a code for django blogging website it is complete but i cant select the category from admin section of the post neither while adding section of categorizing the list of categories in drop down list in not coming why is that.

i tried everything i could.
this is my add post.html

```
{%extends "base.html"%}
{% block title %}Add Post{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1
style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(174, 255, 229); text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 4px;">
ADD YOUR POST HERE</h1>
<table>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form class="form-control" action="/add_post/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="container " style="border:5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0) ; border-radius: 15px; background-color: white;">
       {{form.as_p}}
       <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
           <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" style="position: relative; margin-bottom:20px ;" type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
   </div>
</form><br><br>
   {%endif%}
</table>
<div  class="d-flex justify-content-start container">
<a  class="btn btn-dark" style="position: relative;" href="{%url 'Home'%}">Back</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from dataclasses import fields
from logging import PlaceHolder
from operator import mod
from tkinter.ttk import Widget
from turtle import title
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Comment
from django import forms
from .models import Post 
from .models import Comment
from django import forms
from .models import Category

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=['title','body','category']
        
        widgets={
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class':'form-control'}),
            'body':forms.Textarea(attrs={ 'class':'form-control'}),
            'category':forms.Select(attrs={ 'class':'form-control'}),
        }
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'body')
```

views.py

```
import email
from multiprocessing import context
from re import template
import re
from tokenize import Number
from unicodedata import category, name
from urllib import request
from blogs.models import Post,Category
from django.shortcuts import render ,HttpResponse,get_object_or_404,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import DetailView,ListView,CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from .forms import PostForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy,reverse
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

#def index(request):
#   return render(request,'index.html')
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get the post object being updated
        post = self.get_object()
        # check if the current user is the author of the post
        if post.author != self.request.user:
            # raise PermissionDenied exception if not authorized
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
def AddComment(request):
       if request.method=="POST":
              comment=request.POST.get('comment')

class HomeView(ListView):
       model=Post
       template_name='index.html'
       ordering=['id']
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
       model=Post
       template_name='indexDetail.html'
       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
              context=super(ArticleDetailView,self).get_context_data()
              stuff=get_object_or_404(Post,id=self.kwargs['pk'])
              liked=False
              if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                     liked=True
              total_likes=stuff.total_likes()
              context["total_likes"]=total_likes
              context["liked"]=liked
              return context
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
       model=Post
       form_class=PostForm
       template_name='add_post.html'
       def form_valid(self, form):
              form.instance.author = self.request.user
              return super().form_valid(form)      
class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
       model=Post
      # form_class=PostForm
       template_name='update_post.html'
       fields=['title','body']
class ArticleDeleteView(DeleteView):
       model=Post
       template_name='delete_post.html'
       success_url=reverse_lazy('Home')
class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
       model=Category
       template_name='add_category.html'
       success_url=reverse_lazy('Home')
       fields='__all__'
def Categoryview(request,cats):
       category_posts=Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
       return render(request,'categories.html',{'cats':cats.title(),'category_posts':category_posts})
def LikeView(request,pk):
       post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
       liked=False
       if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
              post.likes.remove(request.user)
              liked=False
       else:
              post.likes.add(request.user)
              liked=True
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('indexDetail',args=[str(pk)]))
```

models.py

```
import email
from logging import PlaceHolder
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from unicodedata import category, name
from unittest.util import _MAX_LENGTH
from django.db import models
from django.forms import CharField
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime ,date

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="uncategorized")
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('indexDetail',args=[self.id])
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body=models.TextField(default="")
    date_posted=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=255,default='tech')
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='blog_posts')
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + str(self.author)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('indexDetail',args=[self.id])
class Comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body=models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return'%s - %s' % (self.post.title,self.name)
```

urls.py

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path ,include
from blogs import views
from .views import AddCategoryView, ArticleDeleteView, HomeView,ArticleDetailView,ArticleCreateView,ArticleUpdateView,ArticleDeleteView,Categoryview,LikeView
urlpatterns = [
    path('',HomeView.as_view(),name='Home'),
    path('Article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='indexDetail'),
    path('add_post/',ArticleCreateView.as_view(),name='add_post'),
    path('Article/edit/<int:pk>',ArticleUpdateView.as_view(),name='update_post'),
    path('Article/<int:pk>/remove/',ArticleDeleteView.as_view(),name='delete_post'),
    path('add_category/',AddCategoryView.as_view(),name='add_category'),
    path('category/<str:cats>/',Categoryview,name='category'),
    path('like/<int:pk>',LikeView,name='like_post'),
    path('category/<str:cats>/', Categoryview, name='category')

]
```

Answer (score 0):

### There is two way populate vales of dropdown

#### Way - 1 (Populate Categoires value as Static values using tuple of tuple)

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="uncategorized")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    ch = (('Category1','Category1'),('Category2','Category2'))
    title=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body=models.TextField(default="")
    date_posted=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=255,default='tech',choices=ch)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='blog_posts')
```

#### Way - 2 (Populate Categoires value as Dynamic values using ForeignKey())

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="uncategorized")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Post(models.Model):
    ch = (('Choice1','Choice1'),('Choice2','Choice2'))
    title=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body=models.TextField(default="")
    date_posted=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='blog_posts')
```

#### --------- form.py ------------------

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=['title','body','category']

        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'body':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'category':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select'}),
        }
```

#### --------- views.py ------------------

```
def DemoView(request):
    form = BookingForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

#### get same output with both way like this

[image]